# UIViewController and inheritance

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

I have multiple view controllers in my application. And in each of them I have to show alerts based on some conditions. Instead of adding alert controllers in each of them, I tried using inheritance as follows.

UIExtension.swift

```
class UIExtension: UIViewController {

    func prepareAlert(title: String, message: String) -> UIAlertController {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
        return alert
    }

}
```

FirstViewController.swift

```
class FirstViewController: UIExtension {

    //somewhere inside used the following
    present(prepareAlert(title: "Error Validation", message: "invalid fields"), animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Similarly, used UIExtension in other viewcontrollers to show alerts. Is this way recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this, you are better off adding your `prepareAlert` method to a `UIViewController` extension. No subclassing required.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func prepareAlert(title: String, message: String) -> UIAlertController {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
        return alert
    }
}
```

Then your view controller:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    //somewhere inside used the following
    present(prepareAlert(title: "Error Validation", message: "invalid fields"), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This allows you to use `prepareAlert` from any view controller include `UITableViewController`, `UICollectionViewController`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is technically correct, although if you consider extending all `UIViewController` instances, regardless of any conditions, then it's more handy to extend it directly:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func prepareAlert(title: String, message: String) -> UIAlertController {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
        return alert
    }
}
```

**rmaddy** was faster. But I decided not to delete the answer, but add another idea.

Another approach is to use protocol as a wrapper for certain functionality, and this is also widely used.

Say, you have a protocol, associated with some functionality, like generating alert, in this case:

```
protocol Alertable {} // or whatever else name

extension Alertable {
    func prepareAlert(title: String, message: String) -> UIAlertController {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
        return alert
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you want certain `UIViewController` instance (or any other class, you get the idea) to be associated with this functionality, simply do:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, Alertable {
   // Now you can do the same:

    present(prepareAlert(title: "Error Validation", message: "invalid fields"), animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

To sum up, making up a protocol and extending it, and then associating certain classes with it - to expose that functionality - is a very handy and useful practice. In particular, this is a good way to encapsulate some functionality, for example, if you don't mean global/class-wide access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Some extension method I am sharing with you that is used frequently in most application you can use it in any where of `UIViewController` class and enjoy :)

```
extension UIViewController {
    let kAPPNAME = "Your App name"

    func showOkAlert(_ msg: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title:
            kAPPNAME, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func showOkAlertWithHandler(_ msg: String,handler: @escaping ()->Void){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: kAPPNAME, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (type) -> Void in
            handler()
        }
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func showAlertWithActions(_ msg: String,titles:[String], handler:@escaping (_ clickedIndex: Int) -> Void) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: kAPPNAME, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        for title in titles {
            let action  = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in
                //Call back fall when user clicked
                let index = titles.index(of: alertAction.title!)
                if index != nil {
                    handler(index!+1)
                }
                else {
                    handler(0)
                }
            })
            alert.addAction(action)
        }
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func showOkCancelAlertWithAction(_ msg: String, handler:@escaping (_ isOkAction: Bool) -> Void) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: kAPPNAME, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction =  UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
            return handler(true)
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) -> Void in
            return handler(false)
        }
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**USES**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
       override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

        //Only Info
        self.showOkAlert("Hello")

        //Info with Okay button
        self.showOkAlertWithHandler("Hello Again") {
            print("Tap to Okay")
        }

        //Show alert with Okay and cancel
        self.showOkCancelAlertWithAction("Hello with Cancel") { (isOk) in
            if isOk {
                print("Okay")
            }
            else {
                print("Cancel")
            }
        }

        //Show alert with actions         
        self.showAlertWithActions("Hello with action", titles: ["Allow","Don't Allow", "Cancel"]) { (tapIndex) in
            if tapIndex == 1 {
                print("Allow")
            }
        } 
    }
}
```